# Printing unicode characters in react-native

Tags: javascript, android, unicode, react-native

I wanted to print unicode string of the form 
 "\u0000c\u0000c\u0000p\u0000_\u0000r\u0000e\u0000a\u0000d\u0000m\u0000e\u0000.\u0000p\u0000d\u0000f\u0000"

Now, it is a string extracted from a json response from an api, so basically I iterate over the json in this way

```
var myarr = [];
  for (var key in jsonResponse) {
     if (jsonResponse.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      console.log(key + " -> " +jsonResponse[key].userFileName);
      myarr.push(jsonResponse[key].userFileName);
      }
  }
```

I am getting the following output:

```
05-23 01:40:59.499  1776  2005 I ReactNativeJS: 0 -> 
05-23 01:40:59.499  1776  2005 I ReactNativeJS: 1 -> 
05-23 01:40:59.499  1776  2005 I ReactNativeJS: 2 -> 
05-23 01:40:59.499  1776  2005 I ReactNativeJS: 3 -> 
05-23 01:40:59.499  1776  2005 I ReactNativeJS: 4 -> 
05-23 01:40:59.499  1776  2005 I ReactNativeJS: 5 -> 
05-23 01:40:59.499  1776  2005 I ReactNativeJS: 6 ->
```

This shows that I have 7 files but when I try to display it in the log nothing comes, I even tried displaying it directly on the app but as we can already see the array is empty.